# Python generics for Scala programmers

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I come from the Scala world where the type system allows for very powerful abstractions.

What I'm trying right now is very simple, yet the Python mechanisms are confusing me a lot: I want to create a type alias that swaps the type params of a `dict`.

In Scala I can do:

```scala
type Pam[A,B] = Map[B,A]
```

But I've tried the same in Python and can't make it work:

```py
B= TypeVar('B') 
A= TypeVar('A')
Tcid = dict[B,A]
def test()->Tcid[int,str]:
    return {
        "asd":1 ## MyPy complains
    }
```

I've swapped the definition order of typevars B and A, in the dict, everywhere, but it just doesn't work.

How can I tell MyPy/Python when creating type aliases, in which order to apply them?

Comment: ...mind, the thing that smells wrong to me about your code is that nowhere are you saying that Tcid takes type arguments in `A,B` order. Leaving them unbound means there's no reversal.

Comment: INDEED, how can I tell Tcid that it takes them in that specific ordeR?

Comment: In Python ~2.13~ 3.12, that would be `type Tcid[A,B] = dict[B,A]`, and the use of `typing.TypeVar` would be unnecessary. I've honestly never tried to wrap my head around the older syntax (and if you _need_ the older syntax, I'd suggest specifying a particular language version in your question).

Comment: Are you sure you're mentioning the right versions? Did Python 2.13 even have generics? because talking about Python 2.5 is talking about a very old python already. I think you may be confused because before Scala 3, it was Scala 2.13, so maybe you're mixing them?

Comment: Meant Python 3.12. I've been typo'ing it as "2.13" most of the last month (a good chunk of which has been spent porting a codebase forward and populating it with type hints).

Comment: Ok, haha, done... Yes, I was using python 3.11, but I'm moving to python 3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in older versions of Python, but in 3.12 (using new syntax specified via [PEP-695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/)) it's very straightforward:

```
type Tcid[A,B] = dict[B,A]
```

Note that as of this writing, PEP-695 is only partially supported in mypy (and even that largely in a "don't crash in presence of valid syntax" kind of way), whereas [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) implements it fully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently do this with mypy.

For Python < 3.12 and for type-checkers which implement support for `typing_extensions.TypeAliasType` (currently only Pyright), you can do the following (see [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmB9ApgDxllAZyTCKiQgTBBigBVEsA1AQxABp7GBBAGyRaEGCLAFgAUBIDSUALxcRrEAAoARFNUBKCUzkLmbNUy0S6AYyQATPcKx8BQxmvNXVnS0jMwA2lM5MAXU54EQwENhYIQlllJk4pTW1JcUssYFgsQhhlTSgAWgA%2BegtLb1QYTiyQAIAuCSgGqBAsGABXEBQoAG9VQUtVGqgARgBfCSA)):

```py
from typing_extensions import TypeVar, TypeAliasType

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")
Tcid = TypeAliasType("Tcid", dict[K, V], type_params=(V, K))

def test() -> Tcid[int, str]:
    return {1: "asd"}  # pyright: Expression of type "dict[int, str]" cannot be assigned to return type "Tcid[int, str]"
```

This was added after a request ([Backport PEP 695's `typing.TypeAliasType` via `typing-extensions`](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/typing-sig@python.org/thread/T5MRLQL7H4Y4HWFA7CBC34MHJCKQEI7L/)).

Comment: But params are not swapped un that example

Comment: @caeus what example? The argument to `type_params` has swapped `K` and `V` around `type_params=(V, K)`. The return value `{1: "asd"}` was to demonstrate that if you didn't fulfil the type of `Tcid`, it would trigger an error. The Pyright playground example has it in the correct order (`{"asd": 1}`).